# How to prove the Delta Method?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems, delta-method

As exercise 9.14 of "Measure theory and probability theory" by Krishna and Soumendra, I'm trying to demonstrate the delta method.

We have a random variable sequence $X_n$, a divergent sequence of real number $a_n \rightarrow +\infty$ and a function $H$ differentiable in $\theta$, so $H'(\theta)=c$, all such that:

\begin{gather}
a_n \left( X_n - \theta\right) \longrightarrow^d Z  \ \ \ \text{(converge in distribution)}
\end{gather}

I want to show that

\begin{gather}
a_n \left( H(X_n) - H(\theta) \right) \longrightarrow^d cZ  \ \ \ 
\end{gather}

The book suggest to use the Taylor's expansion
\begin{gather}
H(X)-H(\theta) = c(X - \theta) + R(X)(X - \theta)
\end{gather}

where $R(x)\rightarrow0$. Now considering the claim

\begin{gather}
a_n \left( c(X_n - \theta) + R(X_n)(X_n - \theta) \right) \longrightarrow^d cZ  \ \ \ 
\end{gather}

it's clear that $a_nc(X_n - \theta)$ tends to $cZ$ by Slutsky theorem but how to show that the remainder part tends to $0$? The book seems to suggest that $R(X_n)$ may be stochastically bounded that would be sufficient, but how to demonstrate it?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metodo_delta) (in Italian, as you are) you can find the complete proof, but I want suggest another approach:

Using Cramér Rao's inequality we have, in general, the following lower bound for Variance of estimators

$$\mathbb{V}[T]\geq \frac{\Big[\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\mathbb{E}_{\theta}[T]\Big]^2}{nI(\theta)}$$

Where $I(\theta)$ is the Fischer Information

If we consider $T$ restricted to the class of unbiased estimator for

1. $\theta$, we have

$$\mathbb{V}[T]\geq \frac{1}{nI(\theta)}$$

2. $g(\theta)$, we have

$$\mathbb{V}[T]\geq \frac{\Big[g'(\theta\Big]^2}{nI(\theta)}=\mathbb{V}[\hat{\theta}]\times \Big[g'(\theta)\Big]^2$$

Comment: I've read you often on matematicamente, nice to see you here. I appreciated both the demonstrations, but the wikipedia's one adds the hypothesis that the derivative must be continuous while yours is formulated in a totally different contest. Here I'm interested in solving the technicality issue raising from the book. Thank you.